# Can anyone figure out what this block of ruby code does?

Tags: ruby

Had this as part of an interview,I guessed it took incoming data, translated it into local language then commits to database? Which was obviously wrong.

```
def optimize(hsh)
  hsh.reduce({}) do |new_hsh, (k,v)|
    new_hsh[k.to_sym] = v.kind_of?(Hash) ? optimize(v) : v
    new_hsh
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it just recursively converts keys from nested hashes to symbols.

```
optimize({'k' => {'l' => 'v'}})
#=> {:k=>{:l=>"v"}}
```

Optimize is a poor name and `each_with_object` should be used instead of `reduce` :

```
def symbolize_keys(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), new_hash|
    new_hash[k.to_sym] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? symbolize_keys(v) : v
  end
end

puts symbolize_keys('k' => { 'l' => 'v' })
#=> {:k=>{:l=>"v"}}
```

This method could be used to make sure that a nested hash has the correct keys. Some devs like to use string keys, others prefer symbols :

```
{'a' => 'b'}[:a]
#=> nil
symbolize_keys({'a' => 'b'})[:a]
#=> 'b'
```

Servers talk to each others with strings but Rails code is often written with symbols as keys. That's one of the reasons why [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) exists.

Comment: Sorry,I'm only a beginner, can you explain where this would be of use?